# How do I manipulate the rotation of the NurbsPath element, so an object like a cube or plane could be animated along its path?

Tags: animation, path

I created an animation in Blender, as shown below (somehow the animation is not showing so this is the link to see the animation: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/9a8tnc0gb75nm3iwcttjo/0001-0120.mkv?rlkey=1rhuw36uo7yjsj6s6dak38o6v&dl=0)

[image]

To be honest, I created this using  the trial-and-error method so that, the plane shown in the video could follow a path from top to bottom along the z-axis. However, I would like to know the real concept behind rotating the path element in Blender so, I could create this animation in blender without going for the trial-and-error method.

I could only rotate the path as shown in the screenshot below,

[image: screenshot]

but can't make it rotate as I have done with the trial-and-error method. I have attached the screenshots below to show the trial-and-error rotation values I entered to create the animation.

[image: NurbsPath selected][image: Plane selected]

Any thoughts would be great to help me understand the rotation of NurbsPath in Blender.

Comment: pls do not link animations to your dropbox here, because if you delete them, your question is worthless. Instead convert it to a gif and just add it to your question. thx. Same with your images, just paste them in the question. thx.

Comment: @Chris: it not only retains the question content but makes it easy for users to see the post content too. that's good. however I couldn't get my gif to be animated although it works in my system. any clues why this happens? I converted my animation file (in .mkv format) to gif using [Zamzar](https://www.zamzar.com/).

Answer (score 0):

you could e.g. use geometry nodes to do this. So with this node setup here:

[image]

you will get this:

[image]

Comment: To be honest I couldn't understand how the Geometry node feature works in Blender. I may have to read more about this.